# Typescript errors on class with generics and partials

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble using a partial on a generic type:

```
interface HasName {
  name: string;
}

class Tools<T extends HasName> {
  public create: (params: Partial<T>) => T;
  createWithName = (nameArg: string) => {
    this.create({ name: nameArg })
  }
}
```

I expect this example to work because `T extends HasName` should ensure that `T` will have a `name` field, and `(params: Partial<T>)` should match any object with any subset of the keys of `T`.

However, there is a typescript compilation error on the line `this.create({ name: nameArg })`:

> Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial'.

Can someone help me understand why `{ name: string }` is not assignable to `Partial<T>`, when it should be based on my logic above?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? I have no problems with your example using typescript 2.9.2

Comment: @JakeHolzinger reproduces in the playground as is https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20HasName%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Tools%3CT%20extends%20HasName%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20create%3A%20(params%3A%20Partial%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20createWithName%20%3D%20(nameArg%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.create(%7B%20name%3A%20nameArg%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: I suspect that the compiler will just not try to reason about mapped types over generic parameters. In your case this should work and there really would be no difference, I'd argue it would actually be more accurate `public create: (params: Partial<HasName>) => T;`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you're right, my IDE just didn't complain about the compiler error. Using `create: <T extends HasName>(params: Partial<T>) => T;` works though, strange issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, TypeScript is right, but as long as you're careful with what you use for `T`, you should be okay to just silence the error with a cast:

```
this.create({ name: nameArg } as Partial<T>)
```

---

As to *why* TypeScript is right here, it's because you can create types that extend `HasName` but for which `{name: string}` isn't a valid object of that type.

The easiest example is just to make a type where `name` is more specific than just `string`:

```
interface HasSpecificName extends HasName {
    name: "alice" | "bob";
}
```

In which case, `{name: nameArg}` where `nameArg` is any string isn't assignable to `Partial<HasSpecificName>` since `string` isn't assignable to `"alice" | "bob"`.

Comment: Why does `create: <T extends HasName>(params: Partial<T>) => T;` work without using `as`?

Comment: In that case, the `T` in `create` is local to that function, and will be inferred from the type of the argument given to it. It isn't the same as the `T` from the definition of `Tools` anymore. If you're familiar with variable shadowing, this would be the same.

Comment: How is the generic type `T` declared at the class level different than the generic type `T` declared at the function level? The generic type is declared the same way, I don't understand how there is a difference, but it would be good to know how they are different.

Comment: Well both the `T` in `Tools` and the one in `create` would be similar in that they both extend `HasName`, but could differ in how they each implement `HasName`. For example, you could write something like `const myTools: Tools<HasSpecificName> = new Tools()`, and then go on to write `myTools.create({name: "charlie"})` without an error, even though `{name: "charlie"}` isn't assignable to `HasSpecificName`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for explaining and providing the cast solution.